# Using Ember.$.ajax() to send data that has relationships

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I'm running through a headache. I'm using Ember 2.0 (a bit old, I know...!). Due to the nature of the project (using ruby-on-rails) we have to use `Ember,$.ajax()` to manage the data instead of Ember-Data. We're trying to send a data object that has a relationship with another data model, but it throw an:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined`

Ember (controller):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  sendFileData(url, verb, filetype, isSelected) {
    let controller = this;

    Ember.run.next(this, () => {
      Ember.$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: verb,
        data: {
          title: controller.get('model.title'),
          files: Ember.A([
            controller.store.createRecord('file', {
              selected: isSelected,
              pdf: (filetype === 'pdf') ? 'pdf' : null,
              html: (filetype === 'html') ? 'html' : null
            })
          ])
        }
      }).then(() => {
        controller.set('successMessage', 'Pdf Data sent to backend!');
      }, () => {
        controller.set('successMessage', 'Something is wrong with PDF data!');
      });
      console.log('end sendFileData()!');
    });
  },

  actions: {

    exportData() {
      let controller = this,
        dataLink = controller.get('model.dataLink');

      console.log('Data link: ', dataLink);
      console.log('Model title: ', controller.get('model.title'));

      if (controller.get('isPdfChecked')) {
        console.log('PDF is chosen!');
        controller.sendFileData(dataLink, 'POST', 'pdf', controller.get('isPdfChecked'));
      }

      if (controller.get('isHtmlChecked')) {
        console.log('HTML is chosen!');
        controller.sendFileData(dataLink, 'POST', 'html', controller.get('isHtmlChecked'));
      }

      if (!controller.get('isPdfChecked') && !controller.get('isHtmlChecked')) {
        console.log('No options chosen!');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Model:

```
// document model
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  content: DS.attr('string'),
  created_at: DS.attr('date'),
  start_at: DS.attr('utc'),
  end_at: DS.attr('utc'),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', { async: true }),
  versions: DS.hasMany('version', { async: true }),
  files: DS.hasMany('file', { async: true }), // here's the relationship to file model

  dataLink: Ember.computed('id', function() {
    return "/export/data/document/" + (this.get('id'));
  })
});


// file model
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  url: DS.attr('string'),
  created_at: DS.attr('date'),
  document: DS.belongsTo('document', { async: true }), // here's the relationship to document model
  filetype: DS.attr('string'),
  selected: DS.attr('boolean'),
  pdf: DS.attr('boolean'),
  html: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

Don't know what to do anymore :(... And we can't add the addon `ember-data-save-relationships` or similar, again because of how the project is structured.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your debug setup. Do you have the Ember plugin in your browser?
Can you post the full debug output?
Have you stepped through the code to see where the error occurred?
You can add breakpoints to see if the error has/has not occurred at that point.

how about something like Ember-AJAX

`

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  ajax: Ember.inject.service(),
  actions: {
    exportData() {
      let ajax = this.get('ajax')
      dataLink = this.get('model.dataLink');
      if (this.get('isPdfChecked')) {
        console.log('PDF is chosen!');
        ajax.post(dataLink, {'files':{'pdf':'pdf', 'selected': true}})
         .then(this.dostuff);
      }

      if (this.get('isHtmlChecked')) {
        console.log('HTML is chosen!');
        ajax.post(dataLink, {'files':{'html':'html', 'selected': true}})
         .then(this.dostuff);
      }

      if (!this.get('isPdfChecked') && !this.get('isHtmlChecked')) {
        console.log('No options chosen!');
      }
```

`In dostuff(file) create a record, respond to error...